# Compute intersection of two identical objects

Tags: java, math, intersection, rectangles

I've got 2 `Rectangles`, both have the same edges.

```
new Rectangle(Arrays.asList(new Coord(1,1), new Coord(2,1), new Coord(2,2), new Coord(1,2)));
```

From my understanding the Intersection should be `1`, however my function returns `-1`.

```
public Rectangle(List<Coord> edges){
        Assert.assertTrue("Provide an exact number of 4 edges", edges.size() == 4);
        this.edges = edges;
        left = getLeft(edges);
        right = getRight(edges);
        top = getTop(edges);
        bottom = getBottom(edges);
    }

private static int computeIntersection(Rectangle rect1, Rectangle rect2){

        int x_overlap = Math.min(rect1.right, rect2.right) - Math.max(rect1.left, rect2.left);
        int y_overlap = Math.min(rect1.bottom,rect2.bottom) - Math.max(rect1.top,rect2.top);
        System.out.println(x_overlap * y_overlap);


        return x_overlap * y_overlap;

    }
```

Do I have a problem with my math there, when computing the intersection or what did I not consider?

Comment: `x_overlap` is 1, `y_overlap` is -1. Either switch the difference for x or for y around.

Comment: @luk2302 But isn't this the actual definition of finding the intersection?!

Comment: I doubt it, I do not know what the value is supposed to represent. It looks pretty meaningless. If anything I would expect to be 0 for two identical objects. I just told you that the output is expected looking at your code, wether it is useful or *correct* is an entirely different matter.

Comment: Why did you post these methods getLeft, getTop, etc? You’re not using them in your code

Comment: I do, to set the values. I'll update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should check if the two rectangle is actually overlapped or not.

And, you should use the min `top` substract the max `bottom`.

```
private static int computeIntersection(Rectangle rect1, Rectangle rect2){
    if (rect1.left >= rect2.right || rect2.left >= rect1.right
            || rect1.bottom >= rect2.top || rect2.bottom >= rect1.top) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        int x_overlap = Math.min(rect1.right, rect2.right) - Math.max(rect1.left, rect2.left);
        int y_overlap = Math.min(rect1.top,rect2.top) - Math.max(rect1.bottom,rect2.bottom);
        return x_overlap * y_overlap;
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect, yeah I mixed up y_overlap `top and bottom`. Thanks for clarification